# How can i know which script file is loading on Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

i have many javascript files with same name but How can i know which script file is loading on Click event.
is there any debugging tool which directly opens the script file and points to the certain function.

please mention how to debug in IE as well.

Comment: In the Network tab in your web inspector (f12)

Comment: having you tried the debugging mode of IE. Just press F12 when you start your application IE. Same key can be used all browsers. A fiddler tool can also be used.  http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome inspector. Find `Event Listener Breakpoints` under `Sources` tab. Check the action name `click`. Now inspector will automatically capture your click events and open up the source file with a break-point which helps you an easy debug. (I don't think IE has such a feature)

[image]